# How can I know the cursor in which edittext in Android

Tags: java, android

I use Android Studio.
I have two editText named: `E1, E2` and three buttons named: `btn1, btn2, btn3`

When I press button, it would insert some word in editText.
For example: When I press btn1, it would insert "cat" in edittext.

But now, I don't know which edittext does student want to insert. How I can detect cursor?
I hope when I detect cursor, I know student which edittext will be insert
this is my code:

```
 private Button.OnClickListener btn=new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn1:
                    s=s+"cat";
                    E1.setText(s);
                    E2.setText(s);
                    //I dont know whether the student want to insert E1 or E2
                    // how can I do,thank;
                    break;

                case R.id.btn2:
                    s=s+"apple";
                    E1.setText(s);
                    E2.setText(s);
                    //same problem .....
                    break;

                case R.id.btn3:
                    s=s+"dog";
                    E1.setText(s);
                    break;   
            }

        }
    };
```

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the focus of EditText:

```
if(EditText1.isFocused()){
  //EditText1 is focused
}else if(EditText2.isFocused()){
  //EditText2 is focused
}
```